# How to prove Campanato space is a Banach space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $p\ge1$, $\mu\ge0$ and $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Campanato space embraces all $u$'s which

$$[u]_{p,\mu}=[u]_{p,\mu;\Omega}=\sup_{\substack{x\in\Omega\\0<\rho<\mathrm{diam}\Omega}}\left(\rho^{-\mu}\int_{\Omega_\rho(x)}\left|u(y)-u_{x,\rho}\right|^p\,dy\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}<+\infty,$$
 where $\Omega_\rho(x)=\Omega\cap B_\rho(x)$ ($B_\rho(x)$ denotes a ball centered at $x$ with a radium $\rho$) and
$$u_{x,\rho}=\frac{1}{\left|\Omega_\rho\right|}\int_{\Omega_\rho(x)}u(y)\,dy, $$

equipped with a norm
$$\|u\|_{L^{p,\mu}}=\|u\|_{L^{p,\mu}(\Omega)}=[u]_{p,\mu;\Omega}+\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.$$

Let $\{u_k\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in Campanato space, one can determine a $u$ because of the completeness of $L^p$ space. What are the next steps to prove that $u$ is also the right limit of $\{u_k\}$ in the sense of $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p,\mu}(\Omega)}$ and therefore Campanato space is complete? Thank you~

Comment: I do not know anything about these spaces - so no much hope to help you. But quick google search led me to the book Kufner A, John O, Fucik S - Function Spaces. They claim that the proof should be almost the same as the proof for Marcinkiewicz space in Theorem 4.2.2. http://books.google.com/books?id=7WZl50M2SPsC&pg=PR3&dq=campanato+space&hl=en&ei=2HgFTq-uMMXn-ga1-Km1DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=theorem%20%224.2.2%22&f=false

Comment: Thank you, @Martin Sleziak. I did google before, using "Campanato space Banach" as keywords, but didn't get much information.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a general result.

**Theorem.** If $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space and $\rho\colon X\to [0,\infty]$ a lower semicontinuous seminorm, then $Y=\{x\in X\mid \rho(x)<\infty\}$ equipped with the norm $\|\cdot\|+\rho$ is a Banach space.

*Proof:* If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(Y,\|\cdot\|+\rho)$, then it is also Cauchy in $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ and thus converges to a limit $x$. Since $\rho$ is lower semicontinuous, we have $\rho(x)\leq \liminf_n \rho(x_n)<\infty$. Hence $x\in Y$. Moreover,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\rho(x-x_n)\leq \limsup_{m\to\infty}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\rho(x_m-x_n)=0.
$$
Therefore $x_n\to x$ in $(Y,\|\cdot\|+\rho)$. QED

Now the completeness of the Campanato space is a simple Corollary. Indeed, to see that $[\cdot]_{p,\mu}$ is lower semicontinuous, it suffices to note that the supremum of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous and convergence in $L^p(\Omega)$ implies convergence in $L^q(\Omega')$ for $q\leq p$ and $\Omega'\subset \Omega$.