# Morrey space and Campanato space.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

I'd like to know a lot about Morrey space and Campanato spaces. For example, I'd like to know how can I see the details presents [here](http://www.zgsm.ch/fileadmin/math/store/fs08/2902/Morrey2.pdf). I'd like some reference about this. I thank you very much.

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47534/how-to-prove-campanato-space-is-a-banach-space#comment105981_47534), the book [Kufner A, John O, Fucik S - Function Spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=7WZl50M2SPsC&pg=PA209) has a Chapter on Campanato and Morrey spaces. Perhaps it might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The book Kufner A, John O, Fucik S- Function space is very useful resource for your study. And in addition the book, the article " what is a ...Morrey space? What is... a campanato space?" Melanie rupflin might be useful.